# is it possible to use value of some key as new key in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

say i have an object list, and each object is type of IUser

```
type IUser = {
 id: string
 name: string
 ...
}
```

I want to convert this list to a map,  use id as key(or other property from object).

And hope I can have an accurate typescript description for this type, so that I can use it like this `const idMap :IMapKeyedByK<IUser, 'id'> = {...}`

```
type IMapKeyedByK<T, K> = {
  [key: T[K]]: T
}
```

How can I implement **IMapKeyedByK<T, K>**?

Comment: Not really sure what you want `IMapKeyedByK` to contain ?  Do you just want to pick some properties from `IUser`?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir IMapKeyedByK should be a map, and key should be `id` in this scenario. like this ```{idA : {...}, idB: {...},  idC: {...}}```

Comment: Note that JavaScript object index types are always strings (or symbols), so this is not very useful. You can index an object using numbers, but they get converted to strings: `({42: 'foo'})['42'] == 'foo'`.

Comment: Do you just need the type for this? Or implementation of how the mapping should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct type here is:

```
type IMapKeyedByK<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K] extends PropertyKey // if the property value can be used as key
    ? Record<T[K], T>  // record indexed by the property value
    : never;
```

It will ensure that you pass a key belonging to `T` and also that the value for that key is valid to use as an object key.

Example:

```typescript
type IUser = {
 id: string
 name: string
 age: number
 department: {
     departmentName: string
 }
}

type IMapKeyedByK<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K] extends PropertyKey ? Record<T[K], T> : never;

type MapById   = IMapKeyedByK<IUser, "id">;   //works - indexed by string
type MapByName = IMapKeyedByK<IUser, "name">; //works - indexed by string
type MapByAge  = IMapKeyedByK<IUser, "age">;  //works - indexed by number

type MapByDepartment = IMapKeyedByK<IUser, "department">; //produces `never` because cannot be indexed by object
type MapByPhone = IMapKeyedByK<IUser, "phone">;           //error - "phone" does not exist
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgqgZwgJygXigbwFBQJYAmAXFAsMngHYDmulAhgLYQlkU273UtSUCujAEYpcBCGHrJgzSsBI4oixWIlSZwAHJMebKrSgBfbEeyhIsALL0wAaQggIBAEIgbAHgAqAGig2oEAA9gCEoCBCgAa3sAewAzKA8APnQEgG0bAF1-IJCwqAAFZGjIKVd7KAB+KAAlCABjaOQCT3SMnySoEkoIADcUAG5sU3BoKzAXGAIlDBgxuwdnVzd4JGQfACJCdcT+pQB6PYB3RojwgFp8UMDHKEEQUnI9bAOlAD0K4fMxly1mFNnrPNHC53CsUBsGMxtrsDsdkKcoBcqGIAjc7g92LQXop3p9RtYXABBbiKGZzezApZgtZQdZcCDQxSwk7nS4otH3fhCETYqC4vFQb4gAAi4kk0hCwH+5IWIOWiHBtJU4vUjIOYCKBD4dQg4QABt0+sg9bd6vQ+EgoHV6JRKNEpcI2dcpujooIAFb1YDPPZvD5mfHjED5AAW0W60sBFMWoIVNPWYDD3UZSlT+z2KCKqAuCaTDKgBGiut49uyeDI2CAA)

Answer (score 1):

Note that JavaScript object index types are always strings or symbols. You can index an object using numbers, but they get converted to strings: `({42: 'foo'})['42'] == 'foo'`. So unless your `IUser` contains `symbol`s, this is not very useful because you might as well hardcode `string` keys.

That said, you can do it. We have to constrain `K` to be a valid key type, and constrain `T` so that it contains a key of type `K` with a value that can *also* be used as a key.

```
type ObjectKey = string | number | symbol
type IMapKeyedByK<T extends Record<K, ObjectKey>, K extends ObjectKey> = Record<T[K], T>

const idMap: IMapKeyedByK<IUser, 'id'> = {}
idMap['zaphod'] = {id: 'zaphod', name: 'Zaphod Beeblebrox'} // OK
idMap[Symbol()] = {id: 'zaphod', name: 'Zaphod Beeblebrox'} // Error! Type 'symbol' cannot be used as an index type.
```

Comment: we are getting closer,  ```IMapKeyedByK<IUser, 'noexist'> = {}```,  what if I want typescript yell at me when 'noexist' is not a key of IUser?

Comment: The above already does that.